# How to get logging working with pm2 and Heroku

Tags: heroku, pm2

Is there a way to tell pm2 to leave stderr and stdout alone (as opposed to writing to files)?

I'm using pm2 on Heroku using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Unitech/4c8ea564aa8bf0a389c5) as my model. Everything seems to work perfectly except that I've lost any ability to log from within my app. They don't show up in the Heroku logs and the files that pm2 creates aren't accessible to me on Heroku's file system (or I can't find them).

Answer (score 16):

In your **package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm i -g pm2 && pm2 install pm2-logrotate"
}
```

In your **Procfile**:

```
web: pm2 start app.js && pm2 logs all
```

Comment: Thx! Installing pm2 globally helped me run pm2 on heroku without it immediately crashing

Comment: `pm2-runtime app.js -i max` instead `pm2 start app.js && pm2 logs all`?

Comment: This is confusing.. Once I used pm2-logrotate all I see is the realtime logs. My historic logs are always just loading...

Answer (score 3):

We just created the official PM2 documentation, here is how to integrate PM2 with Heroku while printing the logs:

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/use-pm2-with-cloud-providers/#heroku-google-app-engine-azure

Alex

Comment: Unfortunately, this guide doesn't tell the most important info — **pm2** must be installed globally and for a proper logging `pm2-logrotate` is required. The bottom line, Liko's answer solves the issue, while **pm2**'s documentation doesn't!

Comment: @Mike wow really , thank God for your answer, i was about to try PM2 docs